# Sample 33078: How to find a specific value in any variable in any SAS® data set in a library

Tags: search, sas, dataset, libraries

I need help modifying this code from SAS (http://support.sas.com/kb/33/078.html) to be:

- Not case sensitive (therefore not overlooking SMITH versus Smith versus smith, I tried "upcase" but it won't work)
- Include a counter (so that I can control for either knowing the first time a value appears and if needed, how many times the value appears)
- Allow for a partial search (this code only allows for exact match to be searched which means I am missing many possible variables that the value could be defined under)

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you show what code you tried and explain how it does not do what you want? Right now your question sounds like a request for someone to write an application for you instead of a request for help with a programming issue.

Comment: data _null_;
        set &librf..&&ds&i;
        %do j=1 %to &numvars;
    if INDEX(upcase(&&var&j),"&string") >0 then /*modified this part to satisfy the first and third things that I wanted*/
          put "String &string found in dataset &librf..&&ds&i for variable &&var&j";
        %end;
      run;  Still having a tough time figuring out how to add a counter in the "put" statement or get it to stop at the first variable found instead of repeating every line....

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

```
data _null_; 
  set &librf..&&ds&i;
%do j=1 %to &numvars;
   if INDEX(upcase(&&var&j),"&string") >0 then 
/*modified this part to satisfy the first and third things that I wanted*/
      put "String &string found in dataset &librf..&&ds&i for variable &&var&j"
   ; 
%end; 
run;
```

So just add code to increment the counter.  Do you want to count observations or occurrences?  That is if the same observation has multiple hits does it count as one or multiple?

Counting each hit is easier:

```
data _null_; 
  set &librf..&&ds&i;
%do j=1 %to &numvars;
   if INDEX(upcase(&&var&j),"&string") >0 then do;
      _count+1;
      put "String &string found in dataset &librf..&&ds&i for variable &&var&j" _count=;
   end; 
%end; 
run;
```

Here is how you might count each observation.

```
data _null_; 
  set &librf..&&ds&i;
%do j=1 %to &numvars;
   if INDEX(upcase(&&var&j),"&string") >0 then do;
      _hit=1;
      put "String &string found in dataset &librf..&&ds&i for variable &&var&j";
   end; 
%end;
   if _hit then do;
      _count+1;
      put "Number of observations so far=" _count ;
   end; 
run;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Question: If I add in "if _count LE 1 then" to select the first hit would this make my program run faster? Or would I need to exit (leave) the do loop? When I add in "leave" I keep getting this: "ERROR 477-185: The LEAVE/CONTINUE statements are not valid within a non-looping/non-iterative DO/END block."

Comment: There is no loop to leave.  You need the `%DO` loop to run completely to generate all of the actual SAS statements.  Not much value in skipping any of the generated IF statements.  Do you want to stop the data step when you have found any of the strings in this dataset?  If so then use an `IF` statement to conditionally run a `STOP` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the code in the sample.  I would change the comparison expression.
I would make it a macro parameter.  You can use FIND/W/C, regular expression, etc.

exp=%str(find(&&var&j,'-target-','IT')),

%unquote(&exp) to replace underlined in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks data _null_, but your code may be too advanced for me. I changed the line you underlined in red to " if INDEX(upcase(&&var&j),"&string") >0 then" but now am stuck on how to add a counter for how many times the value is found in the same variable or to get the program to only report the first time it has found it...